# Rounting in angular2 application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to route to dashboard page on clicking login button. But I'm unable to route to it. I have a login component and dashboard component. I want to route to dashboard page on successful login. 
Login-routing module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginComponent,
                data: {
                    title: 'Login Page'
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'register',
                component: RegisterComponent,
                data: {
                    title: 'Register Page'
                }
            }


];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule {}
```

This is my login html file.

```
    <div class="app flex-row align-items-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-group mb-0">
          <div class="card p-2">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h1>Login</h1>
              <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
              <div class="input-group mb-1">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i>
                                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
              </div>
              <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i>
                                </span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <!--
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-2">Login</button>
                  !-->
                  <button (click)="OnTestLogin()">Login</button>
                  <p>Output:{{postData}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 text-right">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link px-0">Forgot password?</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card card-inverse card-primary py-3 hidden-md-down" style="width:44%">
            <div class="card-block text-center">
              <div>
                <h2>Sign up</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active mt-1">Register Now!</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my app-routing.ts file

```
 export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '#/dashboard',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'login'
    },

    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I am very new to angular and routing concepts. Please help me to route to dashboard component page on successful login. I'm getting the output success on login but unable to route to dashboard page.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at my repository on Angular. It covers the routing concepts very well. For you to have successful login after  check you have to use guards. To check and route. That too is covered please check and help yourself .

The link

https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/tree/master/src/app/guards

Working example

https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/

Comment: I have seen many examples regarding routing in angular2 but I'm unable to figure out the problem in my code.

Comment: @Vai please give that repo a chance i hope it helps pretty straightforward nd only code.

Comment: Why are you using #/dashboard it should only be /dashboard i guess

Comment: I don't know, if I'm  using /dashboard, it's giving me error. Unhandled Promise rejection: Invalid configuration of route '/dashboard': path cannot start with a slash ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:. So, I used #. It's working though if I remove / and #.

Comment: Yes sorry it will just be dashboard , / is already defined in the base href of index.html. hope your problem is solved. Please look at the repo for further router and Angular issues

Answer (score 0):

As of the *official* release of Angular 4.0.0, all of my previously working Routes stopped working with an error that says a path cannot have a leading slash.

That means that my previous Angular 2.4.10 code that looked like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CustomerComponent } from './customer/customer.component';
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/customer',
    component: CustomerComponent
  }
  ,
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/customer'
  }
  ,
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];
```

had to be changed to this to avoid the error:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CustomerComponent } from './customer/customer.component';
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customer',
    component: CustomerComponent
  }
  ,
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'customer'
  }
  ,
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];
```

To avoid using those nasty # in your routes, I would recommend changing your app.module.ts to specify that you want "plain paths" as shown below:

```
import { LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
```

and the providers portion of your @NgModule declaration should add this line:

```
  providers: [
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}
  ],
```